# What are some good resources for designing maps (regional, provincial, dungeon, etc)?

Tags: gm-techniques, campaign-development, map-making, maps

Alright, I hope this question is narrow enough in scope that it's alright for RPG.SE.  What I am asking for is a list of resources such as essays, books, blog posts, articles, how-to's, etc., that cover the topic of RPG map design on all levels, from dungeon all the way up to a continental view, from the perspective of an experienced DM, and not from a technical perspective but from an aesthetic design perspective.  In other words, I am not looking for map design tools (plenty of those to be found across the Internet), map generators, or technical design tips, but resources that cover topics related to making maps more immersive, believable, and useful in a narrative game setting.

Comment: Aside from [all shopping questions being off-topic now](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited) this is also a list question, which is also not a good fit for this site. There are probably hundreds, if not thousands of resources available and to cover even half of them would be way too long to fit within the format of the Stack.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Some of those questions were asked before the current "no shopping questions" policy was enacted; Others avoid falling afoul of that policy by virtue of not being shopping questions as we define them. In any case, this question would be closed here even if that policy didn't exist, as you haven't provided any criteria that would allow us to judge which hypothetical answer would be "best." Without such criteria, our voting system doesn't work, which in turn means that the question is considered "unclear."

Comment: @gaynorvader SE sites don't have a PM type of functionality. The closest you can get is creating a chat room for the topic.